# Helm referring to kubernetes secrets in enviroment variables

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I have some environment variables that I'm using in a helm installation and want to hide the password using a k8s secret.

`values.yaml`

```yaml
env:
  USER_EMAIL: "test@test.com"
  USER_PASSWORD: "p8ssword"
```

I want to add the password via a kubernetes secret `mysecrets`, created using

```yaml
# file: mysecrets.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: mysecrets
type: Opaque
data:
  test_user_password: cGFzc3dvcmQ=
```

and then add this to `values.yaml`

```yaml
  - name: TEST_USER_PASSWORD
    valueFrom:
      secretKeyRef:
        name: mysecrets
        key: test_user_password
```

I then use the following in the deployment

```yaml
        env:
          {{- range $key, $value := $.Values.env }}
          - name: {{ $key }}
            value: {{ $value | quote }}
          {{- end }}
```

Is it possible to mix formats for environment variables in `values.yaml` i.e.,

```yaml
env:
  USER_EMAIL: "test@test.com"
  - name: USER_PASSWORD
    valueFrom:
      secretKeyRef:
        name: mysecrets
        key: test_user_password
```

Or is there a way of referring to the secret in line in the original format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Plan 1 :**

One of the simplest implementation methods

You can directly use the yaml file injection method, put the env part here as it is, so you can write the kv form value and the ref form value in the values in the required format.

As follows:

*values.yaml*

```
env:
  - name: "USER_EMAIL"
    value: "test@test.com"
  - name: "USER_PASSWORD"
    valueFrom:
      secretKeyRef:
        name: mysecrets
        key: test_user_password
```

*deployment.yaml*

```
containers:
  - name: {{ .Chart.Name }}
    env:
      {{ toYaml .Values.env | nindent xxx }}
    {{- end }}
```

(ps: xxx --> actual indent)

Plan 2:

Distinguish the scene by judging the type.

As follows:

*values.yaml*

```
env:
  USER_EMAIL: 
    type: "kv"
    value: "test@test.com"
  USER_PASSWORD: 
    type: "secretRef"
    name: mysecrets
    key: p8ssword
  USER_CONFIG:
    type: "configmapRef"
    name: myconfigmap
    key: mycm
```

*deployment.yaml*

```
containers:
  - name: {{ .Chart.Name }}
    env: 
      {{- range $k, $v := .Values.env }}
      - name: {{ $k | quote }}
      {{- if eq $v.type "kv" }}
        value: {{ $v.value | quote }}
      {{- else if eq $v.type "secretRef" }}
        valueFrom:
          secretKeyRef:
            name: {{ $v.name | quote }}
            key: {{ $v.key | quote }}
      {{- else if eq $v.type "configmapRef" }}
        valueFrom:
          configMapKeyRef:
            name: {{ $v.name | quote }}
            key: {{ $v.key | quote }}
      {{- end }}
      {{- end }}
```